# Unity crashing with DirectX on new computer

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have recently purchased a new computer :

> https://pcandparts.com/hp-gaming-laptop-power-15-cb005ne-acid-green/

And I have installed Unity on it. The problem is that every time I try to move the layouts unity screen becomes black and freezes.

> https://gyazo.com/fdbbba09cbee7005b1b55637cea19855

After trying to search online, post on multiple forums, contacting Unity Team and Nvidia support I have found that the only solution is running unity from the command using `-force-glcore`

In fact, Nvidia support have been unable to find the solution and Unity Team was stressing that I update my graphic drivers and Directx version however both of them are latest versions and so is Windows 10.

> https://gyazo.com/ee810b7d18be7580d3703e42c7b46526
>   https://gyazo.com/ea751dcf39ebfc791f2dce59cd219a0c
>   https://gyazo.com/d43718cc693a7c9cac44f4924bf968da

This is the latest email I have received from Unity Team :

> https://gyazo.com/df2d7e960484cd8c682e5b733860e935

as well as the link for unity forum that also includes the error and editor logs:

> https://answers.unity.com/questions/1511848/unity-editor-crash-2.html?childToView=1512288#comment-1512288

I also tried multiple versions of Unity from 2017 and 2018.

I will provide any additional information needed.

How can I solve the problem so I can run Unity smoothly and without having to go to force-glcore ? And what is truly happening?

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read

Comment: Have you tried downloading another version of unity? Does the same thing happen as well?

Comment: yes I already tried 4 versions , Unity 2017 (latest version and latest patch version) and Unity 2018 the .1 and the latest @SwiftingDuster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I solve the problem so I can run Unity smoothly and without
>   having to go to force-glcore ?

There are other things you can try.

**1**.Use DirectX9 instead of DirectX11. The default on the new Unity verions is DirectX11.

Go to *File* ---> *Build Settings...* ---> *Player Settings* ---> *Other Settings* then un-check the *Auto Graphics API for Windows API* checkbox. From there drag and move *Direct3D9* above *Direct3D11* click *Apply* and restart the Unity Editor.

If  *Direct3D9* is already above *Direct3D11* then move *Direct3D11* above *Direct3D9*.

[image]

**2**.If **#1** doesn't work, try other graphics API. You can try other 3 graphics API such as *Direct3D9*, *Vulkan* and *OpenGL Core*.

These are hidden and you must click the **+** sign then manually add them to the menu then drag them to the top.

[image]

Then you can chose which one to add and then drag them to the top to force Unity use them.

[image]

Once of these should work for you. Chose the one that works the most. You don't need `-force-glcore` when opening Unity to use this. Your issue is mostly a driver issue sometimes, a workaround like this solves it until the driver is fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explication , I did not find Direct3D9 but I have Direct3D12 (experimental)

Comment: It looks like Direct3D9 has been removed on the most recent Unity released. That's fine. Try the  Direct3D12 (experimental). Also try other API I mentioned in my answer like Vulkan and OpenGL Core

Comment: It seems like Direct3D12 solved the issue of layouts going black , however, the response looks slow and every time I write something in the title of inspector for example the tabs jumps slightly up and down , really weird https://gyazo.com/0b8d03cdaa4906b2d2f17147dc3e4a95
By the way , if I may ask one more question , you said : "Your issue is mostly a driver issue sometimes, a workaround like this solves it until the driver is fixed." is this from my computer ? Can I fix it?

Comment: If there is a slow problem with Direct3D12, try Vulkan and OpenGL Core. Don't settle with Direct3D12 until you try the  the other two. Yes, it could be a driver issue or Unity bug. I don't have your computer so I can't do test on my side. Usually a driver problem means you will have to wait until there is an update for your driver. If Direct3D12 works but slow then let Unity know that. Maybe they can fix it in their future updates since it's since in experimental mode.

Comment: I tried all of them , all have the same slowness , at least it doesn't crash anymore . 
So it is unlikely to be a computer hardware problem I guess..
I will make sure to send a report to Unity for Directx12 hopefully they get it all fixed and stable in a new version .
Thank you very much again for your help !

Comment: Well  guess the crash issue which is the main question is now solved. For the slowness issue, look for your Graphics driver [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-pavilion-power-15-cb000-laptop-pc/15551388) under Driver graphics. You need to isntall both Nvidia Rev.C and Intel Rev.C drivers. Re.C seems to be the latest. Ignore the AMD Drivers listed there. Good luck. If still slow, you can try re-installing OS. Sometimes, that helps. If not, then consider returning it and getting another computer model

Comment: Copy and paste the driver link I posted otherwise you might get error when you try to visit it